# Use ViewModelFactory inside Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel

I'm trying to share a ViewModel between my activity and my fragment. My ViewModel contains a `report`, which is a complex object I cannot serialize.

```
    protected val viewModel: ReportViewModel by lazy {
        val report = ...
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, ReportViewModelFactory(report)).get(ReportViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Now I'm trying to access the viewmodel in a fragment, but I don't want to pass all the factory parameters again.

As stated by the `ViewModelProvider.get` documentation:

> Returns an existing ViewModel or creates a new one in the scope

I want to access the ViewModel instance defined in the activity, so I tried the following but it logically crashes as the model doesn't have an empty constructor:

```
protected val viewModel: ReportViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(ReportViewModel::class.java)
}
```

How one should access its "factorysed" ViewModels in a fragment? Should we pass the factory to the fragment?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you shared view model between your activity and fragment class ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-view-model/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#7) official tutorial.

Comment: When I use `ViewModelProviders.of` without factory, ViewModels are shared by default. What do you mean by share?

Comment: The official tutorial doesn't share the ViewModel between fragments. Is there a way to use a factory in a single spot, and then access the produced ViewModel elsewhere without transmitting the original parameters all over the place?

Answer (score 10):

A little late but I had this question myself. What I found is you can do the following:

In your activity override `getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()` like so:

```
override fun getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory(): ReportViewModelFactory {
    return ReportViewModelFactory(report)
}
```

now in your fragments you can do

```
requireActivity().getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory()
```

to get the factory.

Or simply instantiate your viewModel like:

```
private val viewModel: ReportViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: I don't get the possibility to override getDefaultViewModelProviderFactory() in my Activity, I'm not sure where this function is coming from.

Comment: The method comes from [ComponentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity) which [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity) extends. `ComponentActivity` implements the [HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) interface.

If you use a different activity you could always implement the interface yourself.

Comment: No signs of the method in `ComponentActivity`, and no trace of the interface if I search it with double Shift. It feels I'm in a different Android universe than you, but maybe I am. I'm just not sure where to look as I'm still pretty noob to the environment, could it be a different SDK version?

Comment: It could be the Android X `FragmentActivity` vs the deprecated `FragmentActivity` found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity). Else I wouldn't really know.

I supposed you could always add a method or property on your activity that exposes the factory yourself and cast the `Activity` returned from `getActivity`. As long as you use the same factory to construct your viewmodels you should be good.